# old version of flutter_svg not supporting currentColor

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm working in an old version of a flutter app which is using flutter_svg version 0.19.3 to display some svg.
In some svgs I get the following error and the image is not shown:

```
Another exception was thrown: Bad state: Could not parse "currentColor" as a color.
```

In others, the SVG is shown wihout any issue.

I CAN'T update the flutter_svg library as that is going to requires an infinite loop of updating all dependencies up to the flutter sdk version (which cannot be done right now)

My doubt is that in the production version of my app (which is using EXACTLY the same version of flutter_svg the images are display without any issue).

I cannot find any difference between the production code and the development code that justify the different behaviors.

So is there a way I can make those SVG works in any way without updating?
Note: the images are loaded from an url through `urlIcon` property or using `SvgPicture.network`, they are not locally in the project.